# I found a user who has a strange profile activity, should I do something?

Tags: discussion, users

I saw a couple one-letter edits from the same user in the Suggested Edits queue today, so I looked at that user's profile out of curiosity.

Now, I'm probably overreacting and I really don't want to go all out on that poor user, but there are a couple of things I'm having trouble wrapping my head around:

1. First there's the series of mass trivial edits that brough me on that user's profile in the first place.
    I [read on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165878/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-stance-on-users-doing-a-large-number-of-tri) that this is somewhat frowned upon, so I initially raised a custom flag, but that post was from early 2013. Is this still discouraged, should something be done about it?
2. That user has around 300-400 rep, most of it from edits, the rest from 6 answers and 3 questions.
   But there's [this -950 (user removed) spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUiGu.jpg) on the graph.
   Does this mean some other user gave +950 points over these 6 answers and 3 questions and then got removed, negating them? Is that possible?
3. The user made 52 reviews total, in the First Post and Late Answer queues.
   50 of them are "No Action Needed" reviews. That seems wrong.

Should I just leave that user alone?

Comment: _"Should I just leave that user alone?"_ Probably yes. I can't see any points for confirming frowned upon behavior of such user.

Comment: If you think there is something that needs to be investigated, then flag one of their posts using a custom mod flag - provide as many details as possible and we'll take a look.

Comment: Alright. Is there an explanation for the -950 spike, though? I though it only negated an other user's upvotes.

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much about something that shows up in someone's reputation history. If voting has been corrected, then whatever was going on at that point in time has already been addressed by a moderator. It's ongoing or uncaught behavior that should be your concern.

Comment: As far as the size of the reputation change, you can't see any now-deleted posts they may have had.

Comment: Since the spike's so large I'm guessing some batch removal was done (for the whole site). They do such cleanups every now and then.

Comment: `A user of around 300-400 rep`, reviews can only be accessed by 500+ rep.

Comment: @cybermonkey which the user had, before the 950 rep drop :)

Comment: @AlexK Surely a '-950 user removed' would result in an increase in rep, since the user themselves were obviously not removed? Unless 950 of their rep was from the same user, if in which case that'd be rep-boosting.

Comment: No, obviously that says the user lost 950 rep (-950) due to the removal of another user.

Comment: Don't use JPG for screenshots or text!